# Sending and receiving socket messages in Java

Tags: java, sockets, time, nullpointerexception, thread-sleep

We're doing a socket programming project for our Uni. We are developing a file sync software, and we're currently stuck with sending and receiving messages sent over socket.

So, when testing on local machine, code works perfectly. But, when we simulate the server-client environment over LAN and WiFi we get null pointer exception. The files are being sent in chunks so only 5-10 of them pass through.

I guess there is some issue regarding the total time needed for sending messages over socket, and that this is the reason why we get the exception.

Method for sending messages sends the message and starts the timer thread. If no answer is received from the server within 2 seconds, the message will be sent again. Here is the code for sending messages:

```
public static void sendMessage(final byte[] message) {
  try {
    final Thread timer = new Thread() {                
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          System.out.println("timer started");
          sleep(1500);
          System.out.println("timer timeout");
          sendMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1250];
          serverByteStream.read(buffer);
          timer.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }
    };

    timer.start();
    serverByteStream.write(message);
    thread.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {   
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at ServerThread.copyFile(ServerThread.java:372) at ServerThread.run(ServerNit.java:166)

@GregorKoukkoullis Do you want to see the code it is referring to also?

Comment: The whole stack trace. The output you get from `e.printStackTrace()`. You should avoid using the method stop() on a thread, better set a attribute that is checked by the run method of the thread and interrupt the thread.

Comment: Well I would like to know where the error appears in the code you posted above ;-)

Comment: NPEs are just programming errors. They have nothing specifically to do with networking, or time, or sockets, or sleeping threads. There's quite enough information in the stack trace for you to be able to solve this for yourself, and you are really expected to do so as a professional programmer.

Answer (score 0):

When you recursively call `sendMessage()` again, you should kill the `thread` thread also.

Please post the full stacktrace and code where the error occurs also.